# Passing argument without a cast in MPI

Tags: mpi

For my homework I have to test for several large matrices using this Conjugate Gradient Program with MPI (see code below). I copied the program from my book and it is supposed to compile but I get the errors:

> In function 'main':
>
> 37:warning: passing argument 1 of read_replicated_vector makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> 37: warning: passing argument 2 of read_replicated_vector makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> 37: warning: passing argument 3 of read_replicated_vector makes integer from pointer without a cast
>
> 37: warning: passing argument 4 of read_replicated_vector from incompatible pointer type
>
> 37: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
>
> 44: warning: passing argument 1 of print_replicated_vector makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> 44: warning: passing argument 3 of print_replicated_vector makes integer from pointer without a cast
>
> 44: error: too many arguments to function print_replicated_vector

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include "MyMPI.h"

main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  double **a;                /* Solving Ax = b for x */
  double *astorage;          /* Holds elements of A */
  double *b;                 /* Constant vector */
  double *x;                 /* Solution vector */
  int     p;                 /* MPI Processes */
  int     id;                /* Process rank */
  int     m;                 /* Rows in A */
  int     n;                 /* Columns in A */
  int     n1;                /* Elements in b */

  /* Initialize a and b so that solution is x[i] = i */

  MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
  MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

  read_block_row_matrix (id, p, argv[1], (void *) &a,
  (void *) &astorage, MPI_DOUBLE, &m, &n);
  n1 = read_replicated_vector (id, p, argv[2], (void **) &b, MPI_DOUBLE);
  if ((m != n) || (n != n1)) 
  {
      if (!id)
          printf ("Incompatible dimensions (%d x %d) x (%d)\n", m, n, n1);
  } 
  else {
      x = (double *) malloc (n * sizeof(double));
      cg (p, id, a, b, x, n);
      print_replicated_vector (id, p, x, MPI_DOUBLE, n); // here
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

`id` and `p` are not pointers, so I do think I need to pass them by reference in the calls to `MPI_Comm_size` and `MPI_Comm_rank`, though I tried doing that.

**Edit**

//Input Function

```
void read_replicated_vector (
char        *s,      /* IN - File name */
void       **v,      /* OUT - Vector */
MPI_Datatype dtype,  /* IN - Vector type */
int         *n,      /* OUT - Vector length */
MPI_Comm     comm)   /* IN - Communicator */
{
  int        datum_size; /* Bytes per vector element */
  int        i;
  int        id;         /* Process rank */
  FILE      *infileptr;  /* Input file pointer */
  int        p;          /* Number of processes */

  MPI_Comm_rank (comm, &id);
  MPI_Comm_size (comm, &p);
  datum_size = get_size (dtype);
  if (id == (p-1)) 
  {
    infileptr = fopen (s, "r");
    if (infileptr == NULL) *n = 0;
    else fread (n, sizeof(int), 1, infileptr);
  }
  MPI_Bcast (n, 1, MPI_INT, p-1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  if (! *n) terminate (id, "Cannot open vector file");

  *v = my_malloc (id, *n * datum_size);

  if (id == (p-1)) 
  {
    fread (*v, datum_size, *n, infileptr);
    fclose (infileptr);
  }
 
  MPI_Bcast (*v, *n, dtype, p-1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

// Output Function

```
void print_replicated_vector (
void        *v,      /* IN - Address of vector */
MPI_Datatype dtype,  /* IN - Vector element type */
int          n,      /* IN - Elements in vector */
MPI_Comm     comm)   /* IN - Communicator */
{
   int id;              /* Process rank */

   MPI_Comm_rank (comm, &id);

   if (!id)
   {
     print_subvector (v, dtype, n);
     printf ("\n\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: The errors are in the arguments to `read_replicated_vector` and `print_replicated_vector`; we'll need to see the prototypes for those two functions to see what the problem is.

Comment: @Jonathan Dursi these functions are coming straight from the MPI standard library.

Comment: no they're not. MPI functions begin with `MPI_`. I googled your thing and it looks like your assignment includes a MyMPI.h file that declares those. Is this your assigment http://fac-staff.seattleu.edu/quinnm/web/education/ParallelProgramming/mpi/MyMPI.h ?

`void print_replicated_vector (void *, MPI_Datatype, int,
        MPI_Comm);`

Comment: @Adam I have the MPI.h file as well. I don't if I should include that when I compile. Right now when I compile I use mpicc MyMPI.c -o cgradient cgradient.c. Are you saying I should include the header file as well. That link is similar to what we have in the Apendix of our book. Offcourse they are all programmed by 'Micheal J. Quinn' the author.

Comment: You need MPI.h. That's a system header. `mpicc`'s job is to make sure the include/library paths for MPI are as they should be (in fact, `mpicc` is just a very thin wrapper that calls your actual compiler, like `gcc`, with those added include/library switches). What I'm tried to say is that MyMPI.c/h are user code as far as the question is concerned. They don't come from the system, and only you have that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your warnings are because you're calling the function

```
void print_replicated_vector (void *, MPI_Datatype, int, MPI_Comm);
```

with a first parameter of type `int`:

```
print_replicated_vector (id, p, x, MPI_DOUBLE, n); // here
```

C code will sometimes store a pointer in an `int`, and that's what the compiler is assuming you want to do and it's doing the appropriate type conversions (but warning you of them). But to make the code correct you'd have to make the types match up. I.e. pass a pointer to id with `&id` or whatever the appropriate argument is (I don't know what `print_replicated_vector` does or what you want it to do).

Comment: @Adam oh I see. I am going to make that change and see if I still get errors. Thanks

Comment: Now that I look at it again, you're passing 5 arguments to a function that only takes 4... And your order seems wrong. MPI_DOUBLE is an MPI_Datatype, so that should be the 2nd argument, not 4th. The last one is a communicator, likely MPI_COMM_WORLD unless you create others (I don't see you do that).

Comment: @Adam I realized as well that print_replicated_verctor takes only 4 arguments. Again, this is coming straight from the book so I didn't want to change anything assuming it's supposed to run, but I guess not.

Comment: @Adam Any recommendation?? Which argument is extra? Sorry it's a strange question but a clue would be helpful..

Comment: @Adam btw here is similar code for the complete program online. The only difference is the OpenMP pragmas that I am not including. Also the read_replicated_vector and print_replicated_vector is missing but I've added here in my question. http://fac-staff.seattleu.edu/quinnm/web/education/ParallelProgramming/openmp/chapter18/cg/cg.c

Comment: My guess is `print_replicated_vector(x, MPI_Datatype, n, MPI_COMM_WORLD)` This should print your result vector at a CG iteration.

Comment: @Adam Thanks! that took care of the warnings for the print_replicated_vector. Any idea why am I getting this error       37: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Comment: The compiler gives you a line number for a reason.
For errors like that, copy/paste the error message into google and you'll likely find out what it means.

Comment: I changed it to int. the error has gone but since I haven't been able to run it yet, I don't know if it's completely fixed. I get this error and off course I checked with google as well, my guess was it's asking for a function declaration, but even though I added it, the errors are still there                                    1) error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âMPI_Datatypeâ   2) error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âMPI_Commâ

Comment: you're probably missing `#include <mpi.h>`.

Remember that on StackOverflow you should accept answers if they're correct. You do that by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. It's the polite thing to do here, and without it people will stop answering you.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the great help, you helped me get far, but unfortunately it's still not working. I do have the #include <mpi.h> in the program

Comment: Then those are likely to be syntax errors. Probably a missing ';' or ')' or such. Can't tell without seeing the line with the error on it and the few lines right above it.